# use same form to add and update

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, crud

I want to use same angular dialog form to add and edit. Please help me :)
my Component.html with 2 click to add-edit form:

```
<div class="piece-demande-content section-container mb-4 pt-3 container">
  <!--header-->
  <div class="card-header libelle-color-piece-jointe">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 max-with-100">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="{'active':activateItemForLateralMenu===Anchors.LISTE_PIECES_DEMANDEES}">
          <div class="col-lg-1">
            <span class="icon  logo-piece-demandee"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-11"><h4 class="section-title text-uppercase">{{'pieceDemande.titre'|translate}}</h4></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
        <button mat-stroked-button type="submit" (click)="openDialog()">
          <mat-icon class="blue-theme example-icon logo-piece-add" svgIcon="logo-piece-add"></mat-icon>
          {{'pieceDemande.btn-ajoutPiece'|translate}}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Fin header-->
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="mat-table">
        <thead>
        <tr class="mat-row no-border">
          <th class="mat-header-cell ">{{'pieceDemande.piece'|translate}}</th>
          <th class="mat-header-cell text-center">{{'pieceDemande.dateDemande'|translate}}</th>
          <th class="mat-header-cell text-center">{{'pieceDemande.dateReception'|translate}}</th>
          <th class="mat-header-cell text-center">{{'pieceDemande.observation'|translate}}</th>
          <th class="mat-header-cell text-center">{{'common.edition'|translate}}</th>
          <th class="mat-header-cell text-center">{{'common.suppression'|translate}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="mat-row no-border" *ngFor="let element of dossier.demandesPieces">
          <td class="mat-cell "> {{element.libelle}} </td>
          <td class="mat-cell text-center"> {{element.dateDemande}} </td>
          <td class="mat-cell text-center"> {{element.dateReception}} </td>
          <td class="mat-cell text-center"> {{element.observations}} </td>
          <td class="mat-cell mat-column-edition">
            <mat-icon class="blue-theme example-icon logo-detail-edit" svgIcon="logo-detail-edit" (click)="openDialog()"></mat-icon>
          </td>
          <td class="mat-cell mat-column-suppression">
            <mat-icon class="blue-theme example-icon logo-piece-delete" svgIcon="logo-piece-delete" (click)="onClickDeletePiece(element.id)"></mat-icon>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-Component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-piece-demande',
  templateUrl: './piece-demande.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./piece-demande.component.scss']
})

export class PieceDemandeComponent implements OnInit {
  public isFormDisplayed: boolean = false;


  // Accéder à l'énum dans la vue
  Anchors = Anchors;
  date = new Date();
// Dialog attributs
  animal: string;
  name: string;
  // Anchor Menu latéral activé
  activateItemForLateralMenu: string;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  private dossier: DossierDto;

  constructor(
    private readonly iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private readonly dossierComponent: DossierComponent,
    private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly dossierMetierService: DossierMetierService,
    private readonly translateService: TranslateService,
    private readonly snacbackService: SnacbackService,
    private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'logo-piece-jointe',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/icons/logo-piece-jointe.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'logo-piece-add',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/icons/logo-piece-add.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'logo-piece-delete',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/icons/logo-piece-delete.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'logo-detail-edit',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/icons/logo-detail-edit.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'logo-check',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/icons/logo-check.svg'));
  }


  ngOnInit() {


    this.dossier = this.dossierComponent.dossier;
    uiStore.subscribe((evt) => {
      this.activateItemForLateralMenu = evt.activatedItemForLateralMenu;
    });
  }

  /*
    Open dialog method
   */
  openDialog(): void {

    const dossier = this.dossier;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AppDialogPieceDemandeViewComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      disableClose: true,
      panelClass: 'sciven-dialog-style',
      data: {dossier}
    });


    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.animal = result;
      console.log('result', result);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Au click sur la suppression d'un utilisateur
   * @param id
   */
  onClickDeletePiece(id: number) {

    //Ouverture d'une pop-up de de demande de confirmation de suppression
    const confirmSuppressionDialog = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmViewComponent, {
      panelClass: 'sciven-dialog-style',
      disableClose: true,
      data: {dialogText: 'common.confirm-suppression', confirmText: 'oui', cancelText: 'non'}
    });
    confirmSuppressionDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

      //Confirmation de la supppression
      if (result === 'true') {
        let params: RemovePieceDemandeeParams = {
          idDemandePiece: id,
          idDossier: this.dossier.id
        };
        this.dossierMetierService.deletePiece(params);
        this.snacbackService.add(this.translateService.instant('common.success-suppression', {}));
      } else {
        this.snacbackService.add(this.translateService.instant('common.echec-suppression', {}));
      }
    });
  }
}

export interface DialogData {
  dossier: DossierDto;

}
```

-DialogComponent.html:

```
<div class="sciven-dialog-style">

  <div mat-dialog-actions class="mat-dialog-action">
    <mat-icon class="red-theme logo-piece-delete" svgIcon="logo-piece-delete" (click)="onNoClick()"></mat-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container  mb-3">
    <span class="icon logo-piece-demandee"></span>
    <span class="sciven-popin-title-weight text-uppercase">{{'pieceDemande.dialogTitre'|translate}}</span>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="pieceDemandeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
    <div mat-dialog-content>

      <mat-form-field class="sciven-mat-form-field">
        <mat-select formControlName="typePiece" placeholder="{{'pieceDemande.dialogType-piece'|translate}}" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let piece of listTypePiece" [value]="piece.id">{{piece.libelle}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>


      <mat-form-field class="sciven-mat-form-field sciven-mat-form-field-width">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateDemande" placeholder="{{'pieceDemande.dialogDate-demande'|translate}}" formControlName="dateDemande" required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateDemande"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dateDemande></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>


      <mat-form-field class="sciven-mat-form-field sciven-mat-form-field-width">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateReception" placeholder="{{'pieceDemande.dialogDate-reception'|translate}}" formControlName="dateReception">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateReception"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dateReception></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>


      <mat-form-field class="sciven-mat-form-field">
        <textarea matInput placeholder="{{'pieceDemande.observation'|translate}}" formControlName="observations"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions class="sciven-mat-dialog-action-right">
      <button mat-stroked-button type="submit"
              class="sciven-matdialog-action-color validate-icon">{{'common.valide'|translate}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

-DialogComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-dialog-piece-demande-view',
      templateUrl: 'dialog-piece-demande-view.html'
    })
    export class AppDialogPieceDemandeViewComponent implements OnInit {

      // FMode édition formulaire  'CREATION' ou 'EDITION'
      pieceDemandeForm: FormGroup;
      listTypePiece: PieceDemandeeDto[];
      private dossier: DossierDto;
      private create: boolean = false;


constructor(
        private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private readonly piecesDemandeeService: PiecesDemandeeService,
        private readonly dossierMetierService: DossierMetierService,
        private readonly snacbackService: SnacbackService,
        private readonly translateService: TranslateService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppDialogPieceDemandeViewComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
        this.dossier = data.dossier;
        this.create = data.create;
        this.pieceDemandeForm = formBuilder.group({
          dateDemande: ['', Validators.required],
          dateReception: [''],
          typePiece: ['', Validators.required],
          observations: ['', Validators.maxLength(300)]
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.piecesDemandeeService.getPiecesDemandee().subscribe(listTypePiece => this.listTypePiece = listTypePiece
        );
      }


      onSubmitForm() {
        let newdemandePiece = this.convertFormTopieceDemandeDto();
        let params: AddPieceDemandeeParams = {
          pieceDemandee: newdemandePiece,
          iddossier: this.dossier.id
        };
        this.dossierMetierService.addNewPiece(params).subscribe((result) => {
            this.dialogRef.close();
            this.dossier.demandesPieces.push(result);
            this.snacbackService.add(this.translateService.instant('common.success-add'));
          }, (error) => {
            this.snacbackService.add(this.translateService.instant('common.echec-add'));
          }
        );
      }

      /**
       * Conversion Formulaire
       */
      convertFormTopieceDemandeDto(): DemandePieceDto {
        let demandePiece = new DemandePieceUpdate();
        let form = this.pieceDemandeForm.value;
        demandePiece.dateDemande = form.dateDemande;
        demandePiece.dateReception = form.dateReception;
        demandePiece.observations = form.observations;
        demandePiece.idPieceDemandee = form.typePiece;

        return demandePiece;
      }

      onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
```

I'm already implementing my add function with a method I call from the back. I want to implement the edition with the same dialog

Comment: you can pass the id in openDialog() in case of edit and on behalf of it you can implement checks on the component end, you can show prefilled data in case of the edit.

Comment: can you be a clearer or offer me a tutorial :) ?

Comment: @AlokMali  I pass the id in openDialog (id), I check in my console, I get back the good ID but I can not display the fields to edit :(

Comment: @Julius Dzidzevičius, Hello, I saw one of your posts, I hope you could help me

Comment: You have the ID of the selected entry, now you can get data by this ID from the server. And show this data in your inputs. On save, firstly check ID is available or not. If ID is available then call update service and update your data, and if ID is not available then call add service and insert your data.